# Multiple LINQ aggregate functions on different fields apply to the entire set

Tags: linq

Can someone help me here with some hints. Basically I would like to apply different aggregate functions (Count, Sum, Min) on different fields to the entire set (not really groupping), and return the results as fields in an anonymous type. 
Something like:

```
var employees = new[] {
    new { Name = "John Smith", Gender="M", DateOfHiring=new DateTime(2004, 10, 22), Salary=60000 },
    new { Name = "Jane Smith", Gender="F", DateOfHiring=new DateTime(2008, 5, 22), Salary=55000 },
    new { Name = "Kathleen Smith", Gender="F", DateOfHiring=new DateTime(2006, 10, 22), Salary=75000 },
    new { Name = "David Smith", Gender="M", DateOfHiring=new DateTime(2002, 7, 12), Salary=85000 },
    new { Name = "Mary Smith", Gender="F", DateOfHiring=new DateTime(2009, 6, 15), Salary=55000 }
};

var query = from e in employees
             select new {
                NumberOfMaleEmployees = /* Count Where Gender = 'M' */,
                NumberOfFemaleEmployees = /* Count Where Gender = 'F' */,
                TotalSalaries = /* Sum All */,
                AverageSalary = /* Avg All */,
                LatestEmployee = /* Employee with Min DateOfHiring */
             };
```

Is it possible to achieve this in one query?
Thanks in advance
Iulian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be iterating over the array to start with by the looks of it - you just want:

```
var query = new {
    NumberOfMaleEmployees = employees.Count(x => x.Gender == "M"),
    NumberOfFemaleEmployees = employees.Count(x => x.Gender == "F"),
    TotalSalaries = employees.Sum(x => x.Salary),
    AverageSalary = employees.Average(x => x.Average),
};
```

The "latest employee" bit is slightly tricky - you basically want [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), which would let you write:

```
LatestEmployee = employees.MaxBy(x => x.DateOfHiring)
```

(which you can include in the above query, of course).

Comment: That worked but I am wondering how come I should not iterate over the array, whilst in this solution it seems to me like iterating 5 times? Anyway I marked yours as an answer.
And I am still curious if it's possible or not the way I put it in my initial question.

Comment: @Iulian: Yes, this iterates over the array 5 times. If you don't want to do that, you'll have a hard time doing it elegantly in LINQ - it would be better to leave LINQ to one side and use dlev in that situation. Reactive Extensions can help to some extent, but it's got its own trickiness.

Answer (score 2):

While Mr. Skeet's answer works, it does cause `employees` to be iterated 5 times (including the "latest employee".) You're probably better off with a straight `for` loop that tracks each aggregation of interest:

```
int maleCount = 0;
int femaleCount = 0;
long totalSalary = 0;
double averageSalary = 0.0;
object latestEmployee = null;

for (int i = 0; i < employees.Length; i++)
{
    maleCount += (employees[i].Gender == "M") ? 1 : 0;
    totalSalary += employees[i].Salary;
    if (latestEmployee == null || employees[i].HireDate > latestEmployee.HireDate)
    {
        latestEmployee = employees[i];
    }   
}   

femaleCount = employees.Length - maleCount;
averageSalary = totalSalary / (double)employees.Length;
```

I've assumed that employees can be either male or female; you'd need to adjust your code if that assumption isn't warranted.

Comment: I do see your point, but does this mean that we should leave LINQ aside and just use straight loops? The example I used was just for the sake of making my question clearer, in my real case i have to get this results from an EF entity collection.

Comment: If you need to do multiple aggregations with an in-memory datasource, then you either need to use straight loops, or write your own extension method that hides the fact you're using a straight loop. From an EF data source, it's a little different, since the EF LINQ provider can generate SQL that captures the multiple aggregations. At that point, the database can perform the aggregation as it sees fit.